# Bash script to rename PDF files based on filename

Tags: linux, bash, script, bash-scripting, rename

I want to write a bash script to periodically rename incoming PDF publications.

When the PDFs are downloaded they have filenames in the following format :

```
<Pub.Name>-<Day>.<Spelled Month>.<Year>.pdf
```

for example `New.Globe-01.October.2020.pdf`. I would like to create a bash script that will rename these pdfs to the format `<Year>-<Numeric Month>-<Day>_<Pub.Name>.pdf`, for example: `2020-10-01_New.Globe.pdf`. I know that the `sed` command and `mv` are probably useful to do this, but I'm still learning and so don't yet know how to write this. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: There's also `rename`. Or rather [there are](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/108618). This comment is to advance your research; but also to warn you: if you get an answer that uses `rename` then check if your `rename` is not different.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 2):

"Simple" bash commands follow; this to allow a novice to understand.

The bash script below will do the name conversion for ONE filename and display the mv-command to actually do the rename.
The "display only" as the conversion hasn't been tested thoroughly.

**How to use:**
Save the script in your $HOME folder as "script",
cd to the folder with your pdf files,
do

```
$ find *.pdf -maxdepth 0 -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' f ; do . ~/script "$f" ; done
```

... and you will get a list of mv-commands to check.

if ALL the commands are what you want, then do append `| bash` to it and it will actually do the renaming.

**The script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

# catch the first arg to the script...
name=$1 # e.g. "New.Globe-01.October.2020.pdf"

# replace .'s with spaces to allow 'date'-command to parse the date, 
newname="$(echo "$name" | sed -re 's/\./ /g')" 

# replace any 'End-' with "30:th"
newname="$(echo "$newname" | sed -re 's/[Ee]nd-/30 /')"

# reorder the date and name, split at '-', keep the file extension, prepare for date conversion
newname="$(echo "$newname" | sed -re 's/^(.*)-(.*) ([^ ]+)$/echo "$(date -d"\2" -I)_\1".\3/')" 

# pipe to bash to do the actual date conversion
newname="$(echo "$newname" | bash )"

# replace remaining spaces with _
newname="$(echo "$newname" | sed -re 's/ /_/g')" 

# display the way to do the rename
echo "mv \"$name\" \"$newname\""

# mv "$name" "$newname"  # the actual mv...
```

*references:*
https://tldp.org/guides.html  - the bash guides
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-regular-expressions.htm - the regexp:es in sed use above, @ "The Substitution Command"

Comment: The above is safe from use of any(!?) characters in the filenames.

Comment: Thanks very much for this! I just realized that some of my pub names don't have the actual day, just month and year, which means that I get the following output:
`date: invalid date ‘November 2020’
mv "Days.End-November.2020.pdf" "_Days_End.pdf"`
Is there any way to rename both names with the day and those without using the same script, or would that require a second script designed for name format `Days.End-November.2020.pdf`?

Comment: (due to the simplicity of the script this was easy! =>) I added a line to the script. *UNTESTED*

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
#!/bin/sh

pubname='([^-]+)'
day='([0-9]+)'
month='([^\.]+)'
year='([0-9]{4})'

for f in *.pdf
do
    newname=$(echo $f | sed -E "s/^$pubname-$day\.$month\.$year\.pdf$/\4-\3-\2_\1/")
    mv $f $newname
done
```

However, note that this will fail if any of your filenames contain spaces!

Comment: I believe you forgot to convert the date, `date -d"date-string" -I` will do it for you if you just remove the `.` characters.

Comment: Where in this script with would `date -d"date-string" -I` be added to do this?

Comment: The script needs to be reworked a bit, so that it feeds `"$day $month $year"` to date as replacement for `date-string`