# How to recursively rename, sort and move incoming PDF files from subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, find, sed

I have a program that periodically downloads certain publications in PDF format as they become available, along with additional files (e.g. *.nfo), which I don't need. The program places the incoming files in sub-directories named after the PDF file, within the `~/Incoming` directory, e.g. `~/Incoming/New.Globe-01.October.2020/New.Globe-01.October.2020.pdf`

When the PDFs are downloaded they have filenames in the format `<Pub.Name>-<Day><Spelled Month><Year>.pdf`, for example: `New.Globe-01.October.2020.pdf`, or `<Pub.Name>-<Spelled Month><Year>.pdf`, for example: `Days.End-September.2020.pdf`. I am hoping to create a bash script that will periodically scan the `~/Incoming` directory and all subdirectories (most likely using cron) for new PDFs and then rename these pdfs to the format `<Year>-<Numeric Month>-<Day>_<Pub.Name>.pdf`, for example: `2020-10-01_New.Globe.pdf`, before moving the PDFs to specific Publication directories, based on their filenames (i.e. their publication titles). For example, all PDFs whose names contain the name `New.Globe` should be moved to the directory `~/Publications/New_Globe`, while all PDFs that contain with `Days.End` should be moved to the directory `~/Publications/Days_End/`. I would then like to remove any leftover files (e.g. *.nfo) and the remaining directories in ~Incoming.

[With thanks to hannu](https://superuser.com/a/1590833/959307), I've included my script so far below. This works for for all publications with the filename format `<Pub.Name>-<Day><Spelled Month><Year>.pdf`, but I'm wondering if there is a way to make it work for both publications with that format, and for pubs without a day in the filename, with the format `<Pub.Name>-<Spelled Month><Year>.pdf`. I realize that this may not be possible, and I may just need a different script, but I figured I'd ask if anyone knows of a way that it might work.

I am also not sure yet how to recursively remove those directories (and any remaining files in them) from which PDFs were successfully removed and sorted, without risking removing ALL directories in `~/Incoming`.

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=~/Incoming
OUTPUT=~/Publications/

find "$INPUT" "*.pdf" -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' f ; do 
  name=$f
  newname="$(echo "$name" | sed -re 's/\./ /g')" 
  newname="$(echo "$newname" | sed -re 's/^(.*)-(.*) ([^ ]+)$/echo "$(date -d"\2" -I)_\1".\3/')" 
  newname="$(echo "$newname" | bash )"
  newname="$(echo "$newname" | sed -re 's/ /_/g')" 
  mv "$name" "$newname"
done

find "$INPUT" -type f -name "*.pdf" | while IFS= read -r filename; do
  case $filename in
    *New.Globe*)  mv "$(basename "$filename")" "$OUTPUT/New_Globe/" ;;
    *Days.End*)  mv "$(basename "$filename")" "$OUTPUT/Days_End/" ;;
    *) echo "don't know where to put $filename";;
  esac
done
```

Any advice or suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Do you really want it to be a shell script, or would a programming language like Python or Ruby also work?

Comment: Python or Ruby would also work, I just have even less familiarity with those languages than I do with bash commands. I'm interested in learning, but starting from basically 0.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this apparently is a script writing request; based on this -> https://superuser.com/questions/1590802/bash-script-to-rename-pdf-files-based-on-filename/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is with asking for additional help, based on a previous question. Clearly I've put my own work into writing this script, in addition to what you contributed @Hannu Is there some other way to go about this or something I'm missing?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, Super User is not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)?